# Weird dependency with Boost on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake

I have a very weird problem about CMake, Boost and Windows cooperation. First of all - the basis:

- CMake version 3.21.21080301-MSVC_2 (installed with MSVS 2022)
- Boost 1.77 64 bit 14.2 ([this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.77.0/boost_1_77_0-msvc-14.2-64.exe/download))
- Windows 10 x64

I have dependencies, which I found by using the following command:

`find_package(Boost 1.75.0 COMPONENTS program_options filesystem system json REQUIRED)`

So, in the result, `Boost_LIBRARIES` contains the following list (of cource, without new lines, I added them for you to understand easily):

```
...
optimized
C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.2/boost_json-vc142-mt-x64-1_77.lib
debug
C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.2/boost_json-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.lib
...
```

The all libs from the list above exists, no problems about that. I link them in the following way:

```
add_executable(project1 ${PROJECT1_SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(project1 PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

BUT! When I try to compile the solution, I have the following error:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_json-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.lib'`

As you can see above, I linked the lib named `boost_json-vc142-mt-x64-1_77.lib` and now, for some reason, I need `libboost_json-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.lib`. The have almost the same name, except the fact that the second one have `lib` in the beginning. And, it's interesting that `libboost_json-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.lib` exists in the same directory as the first lib. And when I add this lib, like, in a force way:

`target_link_libraries(project1 PRIVATE C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.2/libboost_json-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.lib)`

I have another error: `LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`. That means, that for some reason, my project has a dependency from the `libboost...` library, but CMake finds the simple `boost...` one.

Other things I noticed:

- it not happens if I try to build library (`add_library()` instead of `add_executable()`)
- it happens also for `boost_container`, but not for `boost_unit_test` (I mean, you need to link `libboost_container-....lib`, but the simple `boost_unit_test-....lib`)

So, the question is - why sometimes `libboost...` and sometimes `boost..` are included?
Sorry for the lot of text, but, I hope that somebody will help me! Thank you!

Comment: `libboost_json-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.lib` is the static variant of the library. `boost_json....lib` is the import library. Do you search for the static variant or does another part of the project do so?

Comment: Hmmm. Could you, please, say, what means "search for the static variant"? How should I search for static or import variant of the library?

Comment: See the `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` property in the [description of the `FindBoost` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html). (Even if the module isn't used the variables used in the cmake config scripts are the same.) Import libraries are the .lib files corresponding to a shared lib (.dll).

Comment: Thanks, it worked for one project, but not for unit tests. Unit tests, for some reason, require `boost_unit_test_framework-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.lib` (not `libboost...`), but still need `libboost_json` instead of simple `boost_json`. Any idea why is this happening?